# how to go back to the cause methode(1) after catching an Exception in previous method(2) in java?

Tags: java, exception, error-handling

I am trying to learn about "Error handling with Exception " in java.
I know one of the amazing thing about it, is that you can just handle an Exception at one place and it will be caught whenever the exception be thrown in that section, so I have this codes and I want to go back to the while of `ReservationManager()` after solving the `InputMismatchException` Exception in catch block in `main`.
Actually now when a user type string instead of integer in `ReservationManager` section , the program go back to

> Please select: To book or return the room: 1To Exit: 0

but I want to print

> Please select: To book a room: 1 To check out: 2 To Exit: 3

Actually I want to go back to `ReservationManager` after catch block in main.

I have this part of code in a class named `hotel`:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Hotel hotel = new Hotel(5);
    int serviceNumber;
    System.out.println("Welcome");
    Formatter f = new Formatter(System.out);
    Map <Integer, String> whatService = new LinkedHashMap<>();          //list of model services
    whatService.put(1,"b.a.service.ReservationManager");

    while (true) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            f.format("%s\n %40s\n %21s\n", "Please select:", "To book or return the room: 1", "To Exit: 0");
            serviceNumber = scanner.nextInt();
            if(serviceNumber != 0) {
                Class c = Class.forName(whatService.get(serviceNumber));        //using RTTI!
                c.newInstance();
            }
            else {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e){
            System.out.println("---Please Choose from the options!---");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException");
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            System.out.println("IllegalAccessException");
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            System.out.println("InstantiationException");
        }catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("---Please enter a number!---");
        }
    }

}
```

And this part in a class named ReservationManager which will be created if user enter "1" at First.

```
public ReservationManager() throws Exception{            //constructor
        System.out.println("Welcome to reservation section");
        int service = 0;
        Formatter f = new Formatter(System.out);
        while(true){
            Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            f.format("%s\n %28s\n %26s\n %21s\n","Please select:","To book a room: 1", "To check out: 2", "To Exit: 3");
            service = scanner2.nextInt();
            switch (service) {
                case 1:
                    bookingHotelRooms();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Please Enter the room number");
                    checkout(scanner2.nextInt());
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no builtin "going back" mechanism in exception handling in any language that I know of, including Java. You will have to build one yourself. And the easiest way to do that is to handle exceptions in place where you want to come back to.

Comment: The thing is, if you got an exception, the following code should not either work or be executed. This is the sign that something went wrong. So this should be solve by restricting the size of your `try` block. EDIT : don't instanciation a `Scanner` in a loop, and remember to close it at the end.

Comment: You can store the user choice "1" and use that to "go back" to what was chosen. You should also consider using some Service interface here (but maybe you don't know about interfaces yet)

Comment: such cases can easily be handeled with an `if/else` rather than a `try/catch`. and as mentioned before, do it immediatly at that point and not later on

Comment: @M.Prokhorov thanks, I just wanna using this feature of java that i read in "thinking in java" : exception handling is that it allows you to concentrate on the problem you’re trying to solve in one place, and then deal with the errors from that code in another place. otherwise i should rewrite try_catch again!

Comment: But it never said that it allows you to jump back to the line where the error occurs. It skip the rest of the statements in that `try`. You need to manage that logic to get back where it failed. This is where you need to use multiple `try-catch` to catch and manage exception

Comment: @AxelH thanks, but about the handling no i am sure that it works, i did not write all of my code here maybe because of that you telling this, and about scanner tnx again.

Comment: Then, provide a [mcve] to show that feature. Because in almost 10years of JAVA, I never heard about that this, I lost a lot of time doing it myself.

Comment: @afsane, yes, but you specifically said that you want to "return back" to place where error happened. Which means you can't deal with errors in another place, as at that point exception handling becomes a concern of whatever logic block you're executing right now. If you want "generalized" error handling, extract some error recovery into a common method.

Comment: @RC. thanks, you mean i should write some if clause in my catch block (i know about interfaces if it helps).

Comment: No, I mean you keep the catch at you top level "as is", but store the choice the user made in `main()` and later if the choice is known don't re-ask what service is wanted. (My remark about interfaces was for `Map <Integer, String> whatService`. This could be `Map <Integer, Service> whatService`)

Comment: guys maybe i am not explaining it well, when a user is asked to choose  from this options -> "To book a room: 1", "To check out: 2", "To Exit: 3" and he/she type a string (instead of integer) an "InputMismatchException" Exception ocures and my try_catch in "main" handle it by print "---Please enter a number!---" which is fine by me, the point is after that (because of the while in main) he/she asked for "Please select:", "To book or return the room: 1", "To Exit: 0" which i do not want, i want to go back to reservation section and ask "To book a room: 1", "To check out: 2", "To Exit: 3".

Comment: @RC. i understand but i don't wanna to new "ReservationManager" Again. and as you see i used RTTI so i don't have Previous object name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, i found my answer. The point is that i made a little mistake, i thought that it is better to handle an Exception just at one single place and should not repeat same try_catch in program, but it isn't correct , Actually unlike it isn't bad to handle same Exceptions at different places in program and it is also helpful to find the exact place of Exception. So i am gonna write a same try-catch in "ReservationManager" and handle "InputMismatchException " in there same as my "main", but it is better to show some information about the exact place (may be by logger).